# Numpy equal to not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, equals-operator

I have a dataframe with values `new_df.values`

```
arr = np.array([[ 0.        ,  0.31652875,  0.05650486,  0.11726623,  0.30987541,
     0.30987541,  0.30987541],
   [ 0.31652875,  0.        ,  0.34982559,  0.33382917,  0.00799828,
     0.00799828,  0.00799828],
   [ 0.05650486,  0.34982559,  0.        ,  0.07718834,  0.34384549,
     0.34384549,  0.34384549],
   [ 0.11726623,  0.33382917,  0.07718834,  0.        ,  0.32917553,
     0.32917553,  0.32917553],
   [ 0.30987541,  0.00799828,  0.34384549,  0.32917553,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.30987541,  0.00799828,  0.34384549,  0.32917553,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.30987541,  0.00799828,  0.34384549,  0.32917553,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

And I found the min other than zeros like i.e

```
# new_df[new_df != 0].min().values this is want was used to get this

min_arr = np.array([ 0.05650486,  0.00799828,  0.05650486,  0.07718834,  0.00799828,
    0.00799828,  0.00799828])
```

When I do `arr == min_arr` and `np.isclose(arr,min_arr)` I get :

```
array([[False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Everything is working fine but not the fourth row. May I know why? Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Use `np.isclose`.

Comment: @Divakar I dont know why still no success with np.isclose. Is it only in my computer?

Comment: Show how you are using it and the results?

Comment: @Divakar updated

Comment: Replace `new_df != 0` with `isclose` too?

Comment: @Bharath no not only on you computer.   `df[df != 0][3].min()` resolves as a 0.077188339999999994.

Comment: @ScottBoston any work around. This is only piece of puzzle left to answer another question. Its bugging me so much.

Comment: So, what were you expecting at fourth row?

Comment: It just like when using `eq` in pandas, if you do not point out the axis will received the wrong result `new_df.eq(new_df[new_df != 0].min(),0)`

Comment: Thats awesome and why is axis important? Numpy sometimes feel strange.

Comment: @Bharath base on my understading, those simple calculation like `==` ,`+`,`-`, need to be told a direction.

Comment: for example,numpy.in1d will flatten the narray, to the same dimension  will comparaed array, this will give back the right answer.  `numpy.in1d(new_df.values,new_df[new_df != 0].min().values).reshape((7,7))`

Comment: @Wen you can add your solutions as an answer too :), they are very informative

Comment: @Bharath that is fine , as long as we all clear , that is ok :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to expand the shape of your minimums for broadcasting within `np.isclose`.  Without `[:, None]`, I get the same issue in the 4th row.

```
arr[arr == 0] = np.nan
mins = np.nanmin(arr, axis=1)
print(np.isclose(arr, mins[:, None]))  # need to expand dim/newaxis

[[False False  True False False False False]
 [False False False False  True  True  True]
 [ True False False False False False False]
 [False False  True False False False False]
 [False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False False False False False]]
```

Why the error: when you use just the 1d `mins`, you're comparing *elementwise along rows*.  The confusing part is that that comparison actually looks a lot like your intended solution, with the exception of one cell.

For instance, without expanding to the new axis, comparison of the first row would look like:

```
arr[0] == mins
```

Which doesn't seem to be what you want.